# Why aren't these two matrix multiplications equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not sure why this isn't working as I expected. If $W$ is a diagonal matrix

$$
B = WA \\
C = W^{\frac{1}{2}}AW^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

If W is diagonal, I cannot see a reason why $B \ne C$. I did it on paper and it came out to be equal, and then I tried it in numpy to test it and it came out not equal. I must be missing something simple. Does $B = C$?

Comment: If $W$ is nondegenerate, then multiplying both sides of $WA = W^{1/2} A W^{1/2}$ on the left by $W^{-1/2}$ gives that $B = C$ is equivalent to $A$ commuting with $W^{1 / 2}$---which can be any nondegenerate diagonal matrix. But (for size $n > 1$) a typical diagonal matrix does not commute with every matrix (in fact only the scalar matrices, i.e., multiples of the identity matrix, do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. Multiplying $A$ on the left by a diagonal matrix rescales the rows of $A$, whereas multiplying $A$ on the right by a diagonal matrix rescales the columns of $A$.

However, $B$ and $C$ are equal if $W$ is a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: I feel dumb for not seeing it, but if I scale every row and every column by the same number (square root of diagonal), then it would be the same, no? I don't see the case where it can be different

Comment: @deltaskelta If all the diagonal entries are the same ($W$ is multiple of the identity matrix) then yes they are the same. (This is the last sentence of my answer.) But if the diagonal entries are different, they may not be the same.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks